# CDI timeout results in an NPE

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, cdi, jboss-weld

Is there a way (in JSF 2) to catch a Conversation timeout and redirect a user to a new page?  I'm getting nasty NullPointerExceptions when the conversation times out.

I could redirect the user on all NPE's, but that seems like too big a net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug with Weld 1.0.0 the RI for CDI

https://jira.jboss.org/browse/WELD-550

This has apparently been fixed in the Weld trunk, I don't know in which release it's available.  In trunk, a `org.jboss.weld.context.NonexistentConversationException` exception is thrown, when trying to access an expired conversation.  This Exception can be trapped with a custom `ExceptionHandler`, and redirect the user to an appropriate page.  See this blog for more details on creating an custom `ExceptionHandler`:

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/edburns/archive/2009/09/03/dealing-gracefully-viewexpiredexception-jsf2

Comment: Wow, didn't know that this is a bug. I thought it was me not understanding Weld ;) With the new behavior i can remove some workarounds in my code. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Did you already manage to upgrade Weld to the version in the trunk? if yes, do you have any good hints?

Comment: Haven't tackled that yet...  I'll post in the Weld forum when I do:
http://seamframework.org/Community/CDITimeoutResultsInAnNPE

Comment: FYI: A NonexistentConversationException is thrown in Weld 3.0.1-FINAL (bundled with glassfish 3.0.1).

Answer (score 0):

I'm also currently working with CDI-conversations and trying to build a Conversation-based app. I solved most of the problems (not easy without any useful tutorial out there...). Maybe i can help.

My first problem was that i didn't redirect the view&add the cid to GET when navigating to the next page of the Conversation-UseCase. I asked a related question in the [Weld Forum](http://seamframework.org/Community/NeedAGoodWeldConversationConversationScopedTutorial).
There i learned that in my managed/weld-bean i have to redirect to the next page and add the cid as a GET-parameter.
Only then you can access conversation-scoped elements of your bean on the next page.

So when i enter the first page of my conversation i'm calling a start-method (e.g. by a commandLink) in my ConversationScoped-Bean, like this:

```
public String startRegister() {
  if (conversation.isTransient)
    conversation.begin();
  return "register_start?faces-redirect=true&amp;includeViewParams=true&amp;cid=" + conversation.getId()
}
```

Does that solve your problem?
I also asked a question at StackOverflow related to the ViewExpiredException that has to be handled when working with conversations - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980708/jsf-cannot-catch-viewexpiredexception).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but that's kind of the opposite of what I was hoping to achieve.  I wanted to use an `<h:link>` to "escape" a currently long running conversation.  This should work according to the spec, see the answer I posted.